# Using foreach in Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel, foreach, laravel-5.1

I'm new in Laravel. I'm storing 3 types of user in my users table:

1. admin : user_type_id = 1
2. agent : user_type_id = 2
3. farmer : user_type_id = 3

user_type_id column is in the users table.

In one of my Blade files, I want to only show the names of the agents. Here is my `foreach` loop, which is importing all 3 types of the user (it's showing the names of admins, agents and farmers).

```
@foreach($farmerPoint->user as $agent)
<tr>
  <td>{{ $agent->name }}</td>
  <td>{{ $agent->phone }}</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: What is the table look ? The syntax looks good

Comment: I believe you just want to wrap your `<tr>...</tr>` contents in something like this: `@if ($agent->user_type_id === 2)  <tr> ... </tr> @endif` - see the [Laravel Templates docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/templates) section titled `If Statements`

Comment: thank you.. it worked :) @cale_b

Comment: Can @cale_b's answer be accepted, Noob? Answer acceptance is not mandatory on Stack Overflow, but it is encouraged, because it is helpful both to the answerer and to other readers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple blade `@if()` statement like so:

```
@foreach($farmerPoint->user as $agent)
    @if ($agent->user_type_id === 2)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $agent->name }}</td>
        <td>{{ $agent->phone }}</td>

    </tr>
    @endif
@endforeach
```

Or you can use a collection `where()` since all eager / lazy loaded relations are returned in collections:

http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/collections#method-where

```
@foreach($farmerPoint->user->where('user_type_id', 2) as $agent)
     <tr>
        <td>{{ $agent->name }}</td>
        <td>{{ $agent->phone }}</td>

    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Nice.  Didn't know about where being available at this level.  Cool!

Answer (score 1):

This is probably more of a logic issue than a Laravel issue.  NOTE that I would suggest you limit the $agents instead using your query (where) rather than this way, BUT:

```
@foreach($farmerPoint->user as $agent)
    @if ($agent->user_type_id === 2) 
            <tr>
                  <td>{{ $agent->name }}</td>
                  <td>{{ $agent->phone }}</td>

            </tr>
    @endif
@endforeach
```